# Assign class active to all divs

Tags: html, visibility

I have multiple divs that are hidden and on some pages some are visible.
I use div class="active" to make them visible

But I need to do #div1.active, #div2.active, #div3.active and so on.
Is there anyway to do like div.active {visibility: visible} so all divs that has the class active are visible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div.active {
    display: block;
}
```